# Google Earth Engine Ridge Regression Error?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am intended to get coefficient and p-value from ridge regression built in function in Google earth engine platform. Code runs without problem but for visualisation returns this error:

coefficient error >>> model_coef: Tile error: Input array has length 3 on axis 0, but 2 labels provided.

[image]

code link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/5c67201e60a173f21d067f0ec8f43e30

```
Map.centerObject(geometry);

var start_date = '2000', end_date ='2021'

var era = imageCollection
.filterDate(start_date, end_date)
.filterBounds(geometry)
.select(['temperature_2m','total_precipitation_sum']);


var add_time = function(img){
  var time = img.metadata('system:time_start').divide(1e15);
  return img.addBands(time.rename('time'))
  .copyProperties(img, ['system:time_start', 'system:time_end'])
  };

var add_constant = function(img){
  var cons = ee.Image(1);
  return img.addBands(cons)
  .copyProperties(img, img.propertyNames());
  };

var era5 = era.map(add_time).map(add_constant)


// ridge regression

var model = era5.select(['constant', 'temperature_2m', 'total_precipitation_sum' ])
.reduce(ee.Reducer.ridgeRegression(2,1));

var model_coef = model.select('coefficients').arrayFlatten([['constant', 'temperature_2m'],['total_precipitation_sum']])

Map.addLayer(model_coef.clip(geometry),[], 'model_coef', false)

var model_pval = model.select('pValue').arrayFlatten([['total_precipitation_sum']]);

Map.addLayer(model_pval.clip(geometry),[], 'pval', false)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug in the docs; the output array is sized as: [numX + 1][numY], where the last element in each inner array is the intercept.

To solve your problem, just add another label ('intercept') to the array flatten command.